# Как правильно добавить Procfile в проэкт java maven?

Tags: java, maven, telegram-bot, heroku

Решил написать простого бота для теллеграм и задеплоить его на Хероку. Не очень понимаю почему не добавляется файл Procfile.Ни в jar, ни в списках файлах его нет. В IntelliJ создаю в папку с классами новый файл, называю его Procfile (без разрешения), пишу туда следующее:

```
worker: sh target/bin/TGBot
```

Мой pom.xm:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>TelegramTestBot</groupId>
<artifactId>Bot</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>7</source>
                <target>7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
                <programs>
                    <program>
                        <mainClass>Bot</mainClass>
                        <name>TGBot</name>
                    </program>
                </programs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assemble</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
                <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
                <version>3.6</version>
     </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Сборку осуществляю с помощью команды mvn clean install.
Или я зря переживаю и оно каким-то чудесным образом этот Procfile подхватит само?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно положить Procfile в корень проекта(возле pom.xml). И вставить туда команду запуска, типо такой:

```
web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar target/project-name-1.0.jar
```

После этого нужно сделать jar file с помощью команды:

```
mvn clean package
```

Она создаст в target ваш *.jar файл.

После этого, если вы создали проект в heroku и залогинелись, то нужно выполнить команду:

```
git push heroku master
```

И у вас все задеплоится. Проверить логи можно с помощью команды

```
heroku logs -t
```

Answer (score 0):

По счет записи в Procfile

```
web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar target/project-name-1.0.jar
```

Как понял - она зависит от того, как работает бот через Webhook или Long Polling и в последнем случае тип процесса должен быть: worker.